# daemonUser for upstart not working in sbt-native-packager

Tags: scala, sbt, upstart, deb, sbt-native-packager

I'm using the [sbt-native-packager](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/) to create a .deb package including all libraries. The generated upstart-script is using the `root` user which I obviously want to avoid.

I found a hint in the code that there is a `daemonUser` sbt-setting defined but i cannot set it for my debian packaging.

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes._
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager._
import NativePackagerKeys._

JavaServerAppPackaging.settings ++ packageArchetype.java_server ++ Seq(
        packageSummary := "app",
        packageDescription := "app",
        maintainer := orgName,
        daemonUser in Debian := "ubuntu",
        debianPackageDependencies in Debian ++= Seq())
```

the compile error is: `not found: value daemonUser`

**any suggestion how to set the user for the upstart script?**

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature to set a daemonUser is simply not published yet.

The [IVY file](http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.6.4/ivys/#ivy.xml) of the current released version shows that it was released on 2013/11/16 whereas the [change](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blame/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/packager/debian/Keys.scala) is from 2013/11/21.

Update: There is a release candidate with more Debian support: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/releases/tag/v0.7.0-M1